# Informatica csv output contains # in front of the first column name

Tags: informatica

the output pdo is a flat file type with comma delimited.
After running the mapping, there's a '#' in front of the first column name in the csv output file.

Here's my settings for the pdo:
Run-time write:
Header options: output field names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your infa version is higher than PowerCenter 9.1.0 Hot Fix4, you can easily remove from the hash from the flat file header.
Set the `RemoveOutputHeaderHash = Yes` under the custom properties of the session.

If you want to apply globally, you can add it to Integration Service.​

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Informatica Developer v10.5

Comment: but I see this is a setting done in DIS property. thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: Thats fine... Thx